# Unable to add 12 hours to date ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am new to iOS,

I want to add `12` hours to my NSString if it contains `PM` in it.

I tried this code but didn't got success

```
NSString *str = @"1/1/1900 3:00:00 PM"
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss A"];

NSDate *date1 = [formatter dateFromString:str];
NSLog(@"date1 : %@", date1);

NSDateFormatter *formatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter1 setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
NSLog(@"Current Date: %@", [formatter1 stringFromDate:date1]);
```

**Please help**

Comment: you want to add 12 hours or you want to convert your date to hour,

Comment: can you give any example?

Comment: I want to add 12 hours to my NSString if it contains PM in it. Do you want to add 12 hours to date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close, only made two minor mistakes. First, `A` is not a valid date format specifier, it should be `a`. Second, to convert a 12 hour format to 24 hour format, you need to use `HH` instead of `hh` for the second formatter.

I have fixed the code, run a test and let me know.

```
NSString *str = @"1/1/1900 3:00:00 PM";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
// Need lowercase `a`, A is not a valid format
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
NSDate *date1 = [formatter dateFromString:str];
NSLog(@"date1 : %@", date1);

NSDateFormatter *formatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
// If you specify the hour to be HH, it will convert the date automaticly to in 24 hour format
[formatter1 setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
NSLog(@"Current Date: %@", [formatter1 stringFromDate:date1]);
```

Comment: Third, you need to set locale for the formatter, otherwise the system will overwrite the 12/24 setting by the system setting.

Comment: @Sulthan You forgot to mention that the locale needs to be `en_US_POSIX`.

Answer (score -2):

**try this** !!!

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH.mm"];
            NSString *strCurrentTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

            NSLog(@"Check float value: %.2f",[strCurrentTime floatValue]);
            if ([strCurrentTime floatValue] >= 19.00 || [strCurrentTime floatValue]  <= 7.00)
            {

             NSLog(@"It's night time");

            }else
            {
                NSLog(@"It's day time");
            }
```